# Webform Group Member Composite

Tags: views, 8, webforms, group

I need to create a Webform element that has a list of group members, each with their own checkboxes and text fields ('job description'). I figured out how to display checkable group members through a view, but there's no option for an entity reference-able composite element. Any advice would be appreciated!!

Looking for something like this:

**Group**:

[X] group1

[ ] group2

**Members**:

[X] Sarah       [Example Job Description]

[ ] Johnny      [_______________________]

[ ] Bobby       [_______________________]

Also, a little off topic, but is it possible to use a same page checkbox/whatever element value as a contextual filter for an entity reference element (through the arguments box)? I tried the webform tokens but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: A work around would be to use the [views field view](//drupal.org/project/views_field_view) module and create a separate view block that contains your composite and then insert this view as a field to your original view and pass the ID or whatever you see fit as the argument.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, but I ended up just creating a custom composite with an entity reference field. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest solution was just going into modules/webform/modules/ and extending WebformCompositeBase to create a custom composite with an entity reference sub-element. It's super intuitive if you go off of the webform_example_composite module (included in core webforms I think).

You only really need to alter webform_example_composite/src/Element/WebformExampleComposite.php. If you create the entity reference you want to add as an individual, non-composite element in the webform ui, you can look in build->source and translate the form of it from yml to php. 
A basic Group entity element looked something like this:

```
    $elements['group_members'] = [
      '#type' => 'webform_entity_select',
      '#title' => t('Group Member'),
      '#target_type'=> 'group_content',
      '#selection_handler' => 'default:group_content',
      '#selection_settings' => [
        'target_bundles' => [
          'research_leader-group_membership' => 'research_leader-group_membership'
        ],
      ],
      '#attributes' => ['data-webform-composite-id' => $html_id . '--group_members'],
    ];
```

In the webform_example_composite module, the Submission data is generated by again extending WebformCompositeBase in Plugin/WebformElement/WebformExampleComposite.php and overriding the formatHtmlItemValue and formatTextItemValue functions. If you need custom formatting for an entity reference, you'll have to look through WebformCompositeBase and figure out what to call. I was happy with the standard formatting. Just comment out the custom formatHtmlItemValue and formatTextItemValue functions in Plugin/WebformElement/WebformExampleComposite.php to see what standard formatting looks like for your composite.